# Longest path in a directed acyclic graph with constraints

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, weighted-graphs

Given a directed weighted acyclic graph *G=(V,D,W)* and a subset of edges *D'* of *D*. The problem is to find the longest path in *G* that passes by exactly one edge of *D'*.

What is the complexity of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem in time $O(|V|+|E|)$ by using dynamic programming. Thirst you order nodes in topological order. Let $v_i$ be the $i$-th node in topological order. Let $E_i$ be the set of edges ending in $v_i$.

If $|E_i\setminus D'| = 0$ then:
$$
d[v_i][0] = 0
$$

otherwise:
$$
d[v_i][0] = 1 + \max_{(v_j, v_i) \in E_i}(d[v_j][0]_{(v_j, v_i) \not\in D'})\\
$$

If $|E_i| = 0$ then:
$$d[v_i][1] = -\infty$$
otherwise:
$$d[v_i][1] = 1 + \max_{(v_j, v_i) \in E_i}(d[v_j][0]_{(v_j, v_i) \in D'}, d[v_j][1]_{(v_j, v_i) \not\in D'})
$$

It's easy to see that $d[v_i][0]$ is equal to length of longest path ending in $v_i$ without edges from $D'$ and $d[v_i][1]$ is equal to length of longest path ending in $v_i$ with exactly one edge from from $D'$. After that you need to find largest of $d[v_i][1]$. You can also store the id of the node for which we found the maximal value during dynamic programming to recreate the path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I have weights on the vertices and not on the edges, will the compelxity of the problem remain the same?                                              For the condition |Ei\D'|=0, do you mean that all the edges of Ei are in D' or Ei contains at least one edge from D'?